# Improve background image loading on a site

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, less

My site has a background image and when I load it in the first time; I see the **buttons** etc and the **image loaded about second or two after**,
the image original size was 1.1 MB and after reading the following post I reduce it to **160** KB and still the loading image take time…

> Crystal, G. [***5 Easy Ways to Help Reduce Your Website’s Page Loading Speed***](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-reduce-your-websites-page-speed#sm.0001k9tlsug2ycnlr2x1mtsvkbe7k). *Hub Spot*. 2015-08-03.

There is other way to improve it?

I'm using less like following:

```css
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg-compr.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: There is nothing much you can do about loading the image. You can add a height though so if feels like a placeholder for the image and it dosent shuffle around your content while it loads

Comment: @Sudheer - can you give example how ?

Comment: since it's a background image you won't need height. he meant if you had a block of text after the image, by asigning a hegiht it would leave the space needed for the image instead of having the text bounce up and down until it loads. Not applicable here. One thing you could do is check cache. set it so the user only has to download the image once, the first time.

Comment: Have you done all 5 things suggested yet? If you link to your site it would make it easier to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your JPEG interlaced? It could help with perceived download time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)

I've also had success optimising images via https://tinypng.com/

Alternatively consider giving a user feedback that the page is still loading by creating a spinner:
http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: Thanks but can you give an practical  example what I should do ?

Comment: Interlacing should be an option in the JPEG export function of your preferred image editor

Comment: Helpful tool: http://imgonline.com.ua/eng/make-jpeg-progressive-without-compression.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function backGroundDiv() { document.GetElementById('intro').style.background="../img/intro-bg-compr.jpg" no-repeat bottom center scroll;
}

window.onload= backGroundDiv;
```

If you run this code in your page head part and fix this css;

```
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

It works. I hope it works for you.

Comment: What does it do apart from adding a JavaScript dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

**Step 1:** Open your image in Photoshop.
**Step 2:** Click Save As.
**Step 3:** After Save As you will get a JPEG options.***Select Progressive Option*** and give scan count and click OK to save

this will improve the background image loading time in your site.Your background image quality will increase scan by scan.